# dashboard dim light on dodge journey 2009 sxt v6

Tags: lights

I have 2009 Dodge Journey which the dashboard lights get dim and clock light is dim and inside of my car, light does not turn on. I just get a new battery. Thank u

Comment: There is a "nighttime" setting for Chrysler cars around this year. They will auto-dim the dash at a certain time. You may want to check the owners manual and see if thats your problem

Answer (score 0):

[image: Dodge Journey Dimmer Control]

Most likely you have the inside dimmer switch turned all the way down. Try and find this switch (scroll wheel on the right) and see if you can adjust it to fix your problem.